# stack.size() vs stack.empty()

Tags: c++, stack

to check whether a stack is empty, we can use `if(stack.size())`. Then why do we have `stack.empty()`.
Is there any condition where these results may differ or any advantage of using one over other.

Comment: `std::stack::empty` returns a bool & `std::stack::size` returns a `std::stack::size_type`. In general then if you want to know whether or not a container is empty then you should use `empty`, it requires no conversion to `bool` explicit or otherwise by the caller and the intent is therefore always clear. It may technically also have the benefit avoiding type conversion altogether, though that is implementation dependent.

Comment: Suppose that stack is implemented as a linked list. Getting list size is `O(N)`, checking that it is empty is `O(1)`.

Comment: @Evg That's not correct. [std::list::size()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size) is required to be O(1) since C++11.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I know this. But I nowhere mentioned `std::list` in my comment, and `std::stack` is nowhere mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To some degree it’s a **style choice**.

Personally I think relying on implicit bool conversion should be restricted to things with pointer-like semantics: actual pointers, smart pointers, `std::optional` come to mind. It is ubiquitous in that context and just feels natural.

In other contexts it feels weird. Communicate your intent as clearly as possible! Again in my opinion `if(!stack.empty())` communicates intent a lot more clearly and directly than `if(stack.size())`.

However, style is not the whole story. If you use the *size* style as a general rule it can become a **performance problem**, because you rely on both `size()` and `empty()` to be equally fast.

Imagine a linked list type that does not store its size. Its `empty()` function is still fast because it amounts to checking a single pointer. But its `size()` has to traverse the whole list to determine the number of items. That can be a vastly more expensive operation.